# 400 (Bad Request) in Post request, axios

Tags: react-native, axios

I made a post request to this url  **http://localhost:8000/files/** on postman . It was successful. However, trying the same thing on my react front end produces a **400 (bad request error)**. It also says **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400**

Here's my code:

**submitHandler**

```
 submitHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', this.state.pdf_file)
        console.warn(this.state.pdf_file);
        axios
            .post("http://localhost:8000/files/", data, {headers: headers})
            .then(res => {
                console.warn(res);
            })
```

onFileChange

```
 onFileChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            pdf_file: event.target.files[0],
        });
    };
```

File upload div

```
 <div>
      <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.onFileChange}/>
 </div>
```

I've tried several links without solutions. I'd be glad to get assistance here.

Comment: What is your service build in. If it's express make sure you server is allowed to accept form data. How are you storing images? Are you using mutler? 400 series errors means client's sent data is somehow not in the format the server accepts.

Comment: My API is built using Django.